Custom Scoring Function in sklearn does not work as intended?
Hello folks I am currently diving into the fiels of machine learning using a wine quality dataset from kaggle.
I looked at my data identified and capped outliers, scaled the data, used smote on it (bceause there were 100 good wines and 900 bad ones)
I find f2_score most fitted to classify the quality of my model.
Those are my functions for the f2_score and printing the results:
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix,precision_score, recall_score


def f2_score(y, y_pred, pos_label=1):
    precision = precision_score(y, y_pred, pos_label=1)
    recall = recall_score(y, y_pred, pos_label=1)
    f2 = (5 * precision * recall) / (4 * precision + recall)
    return f2
    
def print_results(y, y_pred):
    print('____________________________________________________________________')
    print('')
    # Klassifikationsbericht erstellen und ausgeben
    report = classification_report(y, y_pred, zero_division=1)
    print("Klassifikationsbericht:")
    print('F2_Score:',f2_score(y,y_pred))
    print('____________________________________________________________________')
    print(report)

    # Konfusionsmatrix berechnen
    conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y, y_pred)
    
    # Plot erstellen und ausgeben
    plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
    sns.heatmap(conf_matrix,
                annot=True,
                fmt='d',
                cmap='Blues',
                xticklabels=['Schlecht', 'Gut'],
                yticklabels=['Schlecht', 'Gut']
               )
    
    plt.xlabel('Vorhergesagte Labels')
    plt.ylabel('Wahre Labels')
    plt.title('Konfusionsmatrix')
    plt.show()
    print(conf_matrix)
    print('____________________________________________________________________')
    
    
def print_best_score_and_params(model):
    print('Best score: ' + str(model.best_score_))
    print('Best params: ' + str(model.best_params_))

while using the standard parameters of the SVC I get already good results:
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score, recall_score

svc = SVC(random_state=11, C = 1, gamma = 'scale') # C = 190 liefter ein ausgewogenes Ergebnis // Standardparameter: C=1, gamma='scale'

svc.fit(X_smote, y_smote)

y_pred = svc.predict(X_test)


print_and_write_results(0, y_test, y_pred)


--> F2_Score: 0.7196969696969696
However if I now try to use a RandomizedSearchCV or a GridSearchCV I always get a way worse score and it does not search for the option with the highest f2_score..
And even hours after debugging I dont know why.
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, recall_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV

search_distribution = {'C': [1,2,5,10,15,20]
                      }
 
scorer = make_scorer(f2_score, pos_label=1) # Erzeugt einen auf der Recall Metrik basierenden Scorer der auf der Klasse 1 optimiert


kfold = KFold(n_splits=3, random_state=42, shuffle=True)

svc_search = RandomizedSearchCV(svc, search_distribution, random_state = 11, n_iter = 6,scoring = scorer, cv=kfold)

svc_search.fit(X_smote, y_smote)
print_best_score_and_params(svc_search)


print('Best score:', svc_search.best_score_)

y_pred = svc_search.predict(X_test)

print_and_write_results(0, y_test, y_pred)

with a randomized Seach with only different C parameters
I always get a result like this:
Best score: 0.9587991499630526
Best params: {'C': 20}
Best score: 0.9587991499630526

Klassifikationsbericht:
F2_Score: 0.6995884773662552
The score the RandomizedSearchCV is using has nothing to do with the f2 score I gave it and so I am not able to use neither random_search or grid_search to find the best parameters?
Do you have any idea why there is such a different score then the f2 score?
I tried using my f2_score as a metric for the best fitting parameters.. I would think that the best_score and f2 score are identical?
I really dont know where this values over 0,95 get from?

The svc_search.best_score_ is different because it has generated based on the KFold on X_smote and y_smote, but your F2_Score has generated based on X_test which might be a more difficult set to predict. Moreover, your random search has only 6 iterations. Increase it.

Ok I understand but even if I used different random_states the best random_set was not really the best. I also used 50 iterations. When I calculate the f2 score manual for every iteration of the  random search and then just use the best parameters of those I still get better results in general I dont really understand.. In my opinion the randomizedSearch does not look for the best f2 score.. you got any Idea what is wrong?

The random search algorithm does not really search for the best score. It is not different from a for loop over a search space of hyperparameters and then sort. If you need to optimize your hyperparameters you may need to use Bayesian optimization which has been implemented in frameworks like Optuna but I personally recommend Weights&Biases.
